# How to update the configuration file and reflect the changes in a Python app running within a Docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I have a Python app running within a Docker container, and I've set up a volume for the config file in the Docker Compose file. I would like to implement a mechanism so that when the config file of the application is modified, the Docker container gracefully reflects the changes by waiting for on going task to be completed and then reload/restart to reflect the changes.

Below is the **docker-compose.yml** file where volume is created against config file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./app_config.ini:/app_config.ini
```

I have used `watchgod` library to detect the file changes and called `sighup_handler` to ensure graceful shutdown when docker container restart initated. Below is the code which is used.

```
import logger
import docker
import json
import configparser
from watchfiles import watch
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import signal
import subprocess

LOGGER = logger.get_logger(__name__)

# Define a signal handler for SIGHUP
def sighup_handler(signum, frame):
    #LOGGER.info("Received SIGHUP. Initiating graceful shutdown.")
    on_change()

# Register the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, sighup_handler)

def on_change():
    LOGGER.info("File change has been detected.")
    # process to restart containers
    process_containers()

# Define the command to restart a Docker container
def restart_container(container_name):
        LOGGER.info("Restarting Docker container {} ".format(container_name))
        restart_cmd = f"docker restart {container_name}"
        subprocess.run(restart_cmd, shell=True)

def process_containers(json_object):
    try:
        # Create a Docker client
        client = docker.from_env()

        # Get a list of all containers (including stopped ones)
        containers = client.containers.list(all=True)

        # Iterate through running containers and retrieve statistics
        for container in containers:
            container_name = container.name                    
            LOGGER.info("Restart container {}".format(container_name))
            #restart_container(container_name)
            container.restart()
    except Exception as ex:
        LOGGER.error("Exception Occurred during config update", exc_info=True)

def watch_for_changes():
    path_to_watch = "/config_updates/app-config-updates.json"
    LOGGER.info("Watching for changes in  {}".format(path_to_watch))
    # Use watch to watch for changes in the directory
    for changes in watch(path_to_watch):
        sighup_handler(signal.SIGHUP, None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:        
        # Start the watch thread
        watch_thread = threading.Thread(target=watch_for_changes)
        watch_thread.start()

        #The script will keep running and trigger a graceful shutdown when changes are detected
        watch_thread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        LOGGER.info("Keyboard interrupted...")
```

Is above approach is feasible to restart the container OR can be achieved without restarting? Will the SIGHUP handler wait for ongoing task to be completed to restart container to reflect the updated changes.
Or shall we have to implement the other approach.? Basically i want to implement how nginx server reloads its configuration and reflects the changes immediately. Please help here to achieve

Comment: How would you approach this problem without Docker?  If your application can observe the configuration file and reload it (or terminate itself) then you don't need to do anything Docker-specific (beyond setting a restart policy).  The application cannot run `docker` commands and I'd avoid writing Docker-specific logic if possible.

Comment: @DavidMaze The reloading of the configuration is functioning well as `Watchdog` detects changes and modifies the mapped file within the volume. Now, I'm seeking guidance on how to terminate a container gracefully, ensuring that it finishes any ongoing tasks before termination. Additionally, I can add the process of restarting the container either through a defined restart policy or programmatically within the codebase after termination.

Comment: I'd recommend solving this problem without Docker.  Since you have some way to detect the configuration file changing, can you reload it without actually restarting your program?  The ability to run `docker` commands at all implies the ability to almost trivially root the entire system, and it won't be available in clustered environments like Kubernetes.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to achieve this without using docker so that it can gracefully reloads.